# Why is Visual Studio Configuration Manager Platform dropdown empty?

Tags: visual-studio

In my VS 2019 solution, the Configuration Manager the Platform dropdown is suddenly empty.

It still shows empty even when I create a new solution.
[Platform dropdown empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4jH8.png)

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you ever find a fix?